# Why archive page can't show full content?

Tags: excerpt

I use "insert more tag" insert more tag for a post.
It works fine, at front page show excerpt, at single page show full content.
but at archive page show excerpt, I want show full content here.
Here is the code in archive page.

```
<?php query_posts('cat=1&paged='.get_query_var('paged'));?> 
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">      
<?php the_content(); ?>
.........
```

no idea what's the rule for show full content or excerpt.

Comment: Some questions. 1. Why do you use your own `query_posts` call on archive page? 2. Why do you use "insert more tag" if you want to show all posts and not excerpt?

Comment: 1.I don't too much about code, just copy somewhere. Basic i want show posts from one category. 2. I want show excerpt at front page and rest of pageS show full content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is `<!--more-->` tag inserted in post, this post will be truncated on lists pages.

You can use global `$more` variable to make WordPress think it's single page though. Here is your modified source:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=1&paged='.get_query_var('paged')); ?>
<?php global $more; $prev_more = $more; $more = 1; if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    ...
<?php endwhile; endif; $more = $prev_more; ?>
```